# Functional versions of C++ copy_if, transform etc

Tags: c++, stl-algorithm

A non-iterator version of e.g. all_of can be written:

```
template <class Container, class UnaryPredicate>
bool all_of(Container s, UnaryPredicate f) {
  return all_of(s.begin(), s.end(), f);
}
```

But I don't think you can do the same with algorithms that return containers?

```
template <class Container, class UnaryPredicate>
Container copy_if(Container, UnaryPredicate);
```

The closest I got to an implementation got as far as using a vector to hold an intermediate result, but tripped over the lack of any way to supply a template parameter for the vector. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: What you are probably want is ranges library http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4128.html

Comment: Why would you use a `vector` to hold a temporary result instead of a `Container` directly?

Comment: @Holt Because when I tried using a Container directly, in the case of std::set, it didn't work; the compiler seemed to think set's iterators were read-only, which does make some sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [`std::insert_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/insert_iterator) instead of using a `vector` to hold your temporary:

```
template <class Container, class UnaryPredicate>
Container copy_if(Container const& input, UnaryPredicate const& up) {
    Container tmp;
    std::copy_if(input.begin(), input.end(),
                 std::insert_iterator<Container>(tmp, tmp.begin()), up);
    return tmp;
}
```

`std::insert_iterator` needs your container to have an `insert()` method, which is a not a requirement of [`Container`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Container) but a requirement of both [`SequenceContainer`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/SequenceContainer) and [`AssociativeContainer`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/AssociativeContainer) (table is not complete, but `[associative.reqmts]` requires it (Table 102)).

---

If you really want to use a vector and all your `Container` respect the [`Container`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Container) concept, then you can access their value type using:

```
typename Container::value_type
```

E.g.:

```
std::vector<typename Container::value_type>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to take the type of (assuming `Container c`):

```
*std::begin(c)
```

either via `decltype`:

```
using T = decltype(*std::begin(c));
```

or via auto:

```
auto elem = *std::begin(c);
```

Comment: _"Do you use `push_back`?"_ Well, all containers provide `insert()` maybe there's a viable way to use it?